# How to write regex in JAVA for extracting comments

Tags: java, regex

I have a comment coming in as follows :

```
//= abcd .
```

There is a whitespace between = and after letter d. Now I need to extract abcd . Any idea?

I have written the following in java:

```
//\\=.*?\\s{2}
```

But it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: here it is //= const 
a$.check(a$2); 
//Src[/INVOIC02/IDOC/EDI_DC40/SNDPRN]
 
 a$1 = new node(1, storage); 
//= FixValues

Comment: Add it to your question. By code I mean, the code which you wrote to extract comments.

Comment: Hi rohit. I have added the regex I am trying in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = "//= abcd .";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=//= )(\\w+)(?= \\.)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if(matcher.find())
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

output = `abcd`

Comment: `find()` returns a boolean indicating whether it found a match.  You should always check that return value before calling methods like `group()` that depend on the Matcher's state.  It makes no sense to call `find()` (or `matches()`, or `lookingAt()`) just for its side effects.

Answer (score 2):

this may work for you:

```
"(?<=^//= ).*(?= \\.)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
//= ([[A-Za-z]+\\s?]+)[\\s\\.]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the lines begin with `//=` and end with `.`
you could also try this:  `//\=\s*(.*)\s*\.`

I tested this at [Regex Planet](http://fiddle.re/3pb1a).

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("//=[ \t]+(.+)[ \t]+\\.$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("//= f+!sdafl,bsadf blargh .");
if (matcher.find()) {
    String extracted = matcher.group(1); // "f+!sdafl,bsadf blargh"
}
```

The regex is:

```
//=[ \t]+(.+)[ \t]+\.$
```